# How can I change the content view controller of a presented popover with UIPopoverPresentationController?

Tags: ios8, uipopovercontroller

The now-deprecated `UIPopoverController` has a property `contentViewController` which can be used to change the popover's content view controller; however, `UIPopoverPresentationController` has no such property.

Is there a replacement mechanism for changing the popover's content view controller?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you can access the content view controller from the "presentedViewController" property of the UIPopoverPresentationController.

You can also go the other direction from within the content view controller, where you have a reference to the UIPopoverPresentationController via the popoverPresentationController property.

I hope that is right - I'm just researching this now myself, and that is my best understanding of what I have seen so far.

Comment: No, that's not right. The property you mentioned is readonly.

Answer (score -1):

You can find an example to how to use the UIPOpoverPresentationController here:

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/resources/sample-code/

Search for "LookInside: Presentation Controllers Adaptivity and Custom Animator Objects"

Comment: This link has expired, so this is no longer an answer.

Comment: But why downvote? When i replied the link was working. By the way the UIPopoverController is not deprecated...